# "External call transformation" lost configuration in "call transformation settings" on dataflow when a page is refreshed

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow with an "external call transformation", I fill in all fields in configuration "call transformation settings", but when I refreshed the page my settings filled losted.

My filled settings

[My filled settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rew9T.png)

When I refreshed the page

[When I refreshed the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e50k5.png)

Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to Publish DataFlow activity in order to save Configuration. When data factory is not connected to any repository, it is said to operate in Live mode. In this mode, if you don't publish the changes, those will be lost once you refresh the page. It is essentially same as "Save" option.

Before page refresh, Publish Dataflow activity.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/99957/what-does-publishing-do-in-azure-data-factory-do.html

Comment: Hello @AbhishekKhandave-M, I'm using git as repository, and I publish project successful, but anyway, when I back to the page, my settings was lost. I'm using synapse integrated and don't data factory.

Comment: This also happens to me with GIT repo settings. I set the Column mappings, save it.  Then later when I go back into the Data Flow, the mappings have disappeared. Doesn't happen to other objects, seems to be a problem with only the External Call object. Also sometimes drops the additional headers.